# HTTPS issue "Your connection is not private", Ngnix

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to get HTTPS work on all subdomains using"Nginx", but receive:

`This server could not prove that it is api.wokcraft.com; its security certificate is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.`

URL: https://api.wokcraft.com/

Can any one inform what missing?
thx

edit: I followed this instructions: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1091/0/certificate-installation--nginx

Answer (score 1):

Nginx doesn't send the correct list of intermediate certificates: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.wokcraft.com&latest

Comment: I merged "Ngnix CRT" & "SSL bundle", what I should do next?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the correct bundle:

You want to create Comodo Bundle this way (replacing **your_cert** with actual name of your file):

```
cat your_cert.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > your_cert.ca-bundle
```

2. Get the new ca-bundle onto your server

Once that is done copy this to your server as in the Nginx set it this way:

```
ssl_certificate /your/ssl/path/your_cert.ca-bundle;
ssl_certificate_key /your/ssl/path/your_cert_privateKey.key;
```

3. Verify the cert and key are matching after they have been copied (compare md5 hashes).

   openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.crt | openssl md5

   openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in privateKey.key | openssl md5
4. Test the config (need to run as sudo):

   sudo nginx -t
5. If no errors, reload nginx and re-run you SSLlabs check:

   https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.wokcraft.com

Comment: run: `sudo cat wokcraft.api.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > wokcraft.api.ca-bundle`
( -bash: wokcraft.api.ca-bundle: Permission denied )

Comment: I'm not sure what is that `run:` are you running this as part of some script? Does it have the right permissions to access the file?

In the worst scenario  you can manually open each on the files and copy-paste as long as the order is the same. **Although it's the easies way to mess it up**. So I would advise not to do that unless everything else fails.